# Why there is no simulators in my Target?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, project

I searched the stackoverflow, and find litte, ask me to install the simulators from Xcode.I think this is not the solution.

Because my other project has the list of simulators.

Compire:

There is no simulators in the Target:

[image]

There have whole list of simulators in my other project:

[image]

So, I don't think this is Xcode's cause, where is the issue make my first project no simulators?

Comment: Please mention the version of the Xcode and the iOS deployment target of the application?

Comment: @ Imad Ali, Thank you, your mention let me solve the issue.

Comment: Happy Coding..!

Comment: @Imad Ali, you can answer this question, because this is your metion, I can solve it, come on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your Application deployment target is lower than the iOS Simulator version.

For deployment target check:

```
TARGETS -> General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target
```

For example, if your iOS Simulator version is 10.0 make sure that deployment target is lower than 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

With the  Imad Ali's mention, I found the `TARGETS` -> `General` -> `Deployment Info` -> `Deployment Target` is `10.2` defaultly.

So I change it to `8.0`, then the list of simulators comes out.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to two reasons:

**First Reason:**

Your `Deployment Targe`t is set to above your `Xcode` `base SDK iOS` version.

*For Example*: You have got this project from somewhere and it is created on above `Xcode` version (like: `Xcode 8.2` ) and its `Deployment Target` set to `iOS 10.2` and you might have `Xcode 8.0`, So when you open that project so it creates the same issues which you have mentioned.

*Resolved it using:*

Project Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target set it to equal or below to your Xcode version like iOS 10.0 or iOS 9.0 if you have Xcode 8.0

**Second Reason:**

It might be the Xcode Bug:

- Force Quit and open again Xcode it will show all the devices.